# Unable to access Docker Application via browser

Tags: linux, docker, containers, port, tableau-api

I am attempting to install a Tableau server running in a Docker Container and I seem to having a lot of issues accessing the application via my browser after the install.

I was able to create the docker image with no issues

```
REPOSITORY             TAG                  IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
tableau_server_image   20214.22.0314.1536   18f33191a8c5   10 hours ago   8.68GB
centos                 7.9.2009             eeb6ee3f44bd   6 months ago   204MB
pvtmert/tableau        latest               31c0207b828b   7 months ago   4.1GB
```

Also the container seems to currently be running

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                                                              NAMES
5fd0604d7edc   18f33191a8c5   "/bin/sh -c ${DOCKER…"   6 hours ago   Up 6 hours   0.0.0.0:8850->8850/tcp, :::8850->8850/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp, :::80->8080/tcp   zen_solomon
```

However, whenever I attempt to access the application via the public IP on either ports 8850 or port 80, nothing comes up.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Do I have the ports wrongly configured?

These are my results when I run `netstat -ntlp`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22654/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8850            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22632/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1112/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      22662/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::8850                 :::*                    LISTEN      22638/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1112/sshd
```

Comment: how do you run the docker? with docker-compose or docker run ? show the docker-compose file or your docker run command.

Comment: @aSaffary Sure thing... I am using docker run and this is my docker run command:

`docker run -e TSM_ONLY=1 -p 80:8080 -p 8850:8850 -d 18f33191a8c5`

Comment: I have the same issue, for portainer. there's no compose file for that